# gridview dataBind isn't working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This is my code to bind gridview. But when I run I see nothing (no gridview just empty) but when I use sqldatsource I can bind all.
How can I fix this?

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yol);

        conn.Open();

    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from duyuru", conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" AllowPaging="True" 
                    BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you add your GridView code as well?

Comment: Are you sure there's data in the table you're querying?

Comment: ofc , i am sure i can bind with sqldatasource and datas comes but i cannot bind with code!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yol);

        conn.Open();

    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from duyuru", conn);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

             adapter.Fill(ds, "Products");//here enter your table name

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i tried this way so many times but it isnt working and i dont know why? all about vs2008?